# ag grid server side model. Prevent grid data from being erased until new data is obtained

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid

I am using ag-grid datagrid to display data obtained from my backend using SSRM (Server Side Row Model).

I need to implement custom filters. Every time the user changes the data in the filter I have to call the method filterChangedCallback(), this fires a sequence and then, in another class that implements the IServerSideDatasource interface, the getrows method is called and I can retrieve new data from my backend (sending the filter values).

That's fine and that's what I need, but before calling getrows, another process is destroying the data and the ag-grid is empty, this is a problem for me. The question is that I don't know from where this data destroyer process is called.

I guess probably I can implement another interface in my class and overwrite that method that is deleting the data the problem is that I can't find related information on the ag-grid website.

Does anyone know if there is a way to avoid deleting the data before calling getrows?

Thanks for reading ;-)

Comment: I finally found another way to solve my problem using custom filters.
Thank you.

Comment: how did yo resolve this?